com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.activation.DataHandler
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyDocumentServiceResponse {
@JsonProperty("Status")
protected String status;

@JsonProperty("DocumentClassName")
protected String documentClassName;

@JsonProperty("FileName")
protected String fileName;

@JsonProperty("MimeType")
protected String mimeType;

@JsonProperty("DocumentContent")
@JsonIgnore
protected DataHandler documentContent;

I am trying to fetch the response via HTTPPost call and able to retrieve the response but getting
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of \`javax.activation.DataHandler at below line

MyDocumentServiceResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(serviceResponse.getMessage(), MyDocumentServiceResponse.class);\

Please advise me how to fix this, I've tried all the possible ways but no luck.
